# How to print a returned value in Python

Tags: python, function, return

I am learning functions in Python and was asked to make a script that takes two inputed values and does some math function on them. I wrote the code below but keep getting the error message that on line 17 where I try to print the answer, 'result' is not defined. I dont understand this as I feel like I am defining 'result' within each function. Clearly I am missing some basic concept related to functions and returned values. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def sum(a,b):
    result = a + b
    return result

def times(a,b):
    result = a * b
    return result

def divide(a,b):
    result = a / b
    return result

def subtract(a,b):
    result = a / b
    return result

print "Answer is %d" % result

def start():
    print "This program can perfom a math function of any two numbers"
    a = int(raw_input("Enter first number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter second number: "))
    c = raw_input("Enter math function you want: ")

    if c == "+":
        sum(a,b)
    elif c == "x":
        times(a,b)
    elif c == "/":
        divide(a,b)
    elif c == "-":
        subtract(a,b)
    else:
        print "you didnt enter a function!"

start()
```

Here is the error:
File "defPrac2.py", line 17, in 
    print "Answer is %d" % result

Comment: As the error message tells you, on line 17, `result` is not defined. What do you expect this value to be, on line 17?

Comment: Isn't result defined within each function ie result = a+b etc? I expected that line 17 would print the answer to the equation from whichever function is called.

Comment: First of all, variables defined in functions are local to the function, not visible outside. Secondly, as of line 17, none of the functions have been invoked yet. They were defined, but not yet used. They have not been called yet.

Comment: There are many things wrong in this code, so it can't properly focus on a clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the problem is you are not returning anything from the start function  , 
again Python follows a indentation level i.e anything written on the first level (line with no space will be executed first ),

remove the line print line from the top and modify the start function to return the value :

```
def start():
    print "This program can perfom a math function of any two numbers"
    a = int(raw_input("Enter first number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter second number: "))
    c = raw_input("Enter math function you want: ")
    res = -1
    if c == "+":
        res = sum(a,b)
    elif c == "x":
        res = times(a,b)
    elif c == "/":
        res = divide(a,b)
    elif c == "-":
        res = subtract(a,b)
    else:
        print "you didnt enter a function!"
    return res
result = start()
# use format instead of access specifier as it may give you error if 
# not handling the specific type case format is more generic
print "Answer is {0}".format(result)
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: This is very helpful - thanks! I still dont get why each function is not returning the value that is calculated so that it can be printed subsequently at line 17. If I put the print statement in the function it prints Ok.

Comment: Better you attend some basic classes on python, what you are trying is totally wrong ,

Comment: Look at @csharpcoder's code, and how he assigns the return value of each function call to a variable called res. Then maybe read a python tutorial, eg docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Try this, when you have return values, either you can put that value in a new variable and then print or directly print in in the print statement.
`

```
def sum(a,b):
    result = a + b
    return result

def times(a,b):
    result = a * b
    return result

def divide(a,b):
    result = a / b
    return result

def subtract(a,b):
    result = a / b
    return result

def start():
    print "This program can perfom a math function of any two numbers"
    a = int(raw_input("Enter first number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter second number: "))
    c = raw_input("Enter math function you want: ")

    if c == "+":
        print("The answer is "+sum(a,b))
    elif c == "x":
        print("The answer is "+times(a,b))
    elif c == "/":
        print("The answer is "+divide(a,b))
    elif c == "-":
        print("The answer is "+subtract(a,b))
    else:
        print "you didnt enter a function!"

start()
```

`